# How many magical entities exist in the world of Bartimaeus?

Tags: bartimaeus, jonathan-stroud

In the Bartimaeus books magical entities are "killed" all the time. This is notably different from just returning to the "other place", they actually stop existing. As far as I know there is no mention of new entities being created in any way ever. So I would assume that their total number only ever decreases since wizards started summoning them. Bartimaeus also keeps encountering familiar faces, so I would assume that there aren't quintillions of entities to "use up" over time.

So the question is: How many are left? Is there a rough estimate in any canon material? Are they in danger of dying out? Or can new ones be "born"/"created" in any way?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it may help to provide some indication, and it's the most pertinent piece of information I've found (so far) in the books.

From Lovelace's first meeting with Nathaniel, when he's testing his knowledge as a boy:

> "How many classified types of spirit are there?"
>
> Nathaniel replied without a pause. "Thirteen thousand and forty-six, sir."
>
> "And unclassified?"
>
> "Petronius postulates forty-five thousand; Zavattini forty-eight thousand, sir."

So the number of *types* of spirit is somewhere in the tens of thousands. What exactly is meant by "types" isn't clear, and how many spirits there are of each type is likely to vary a lot: there are probably untold hundreds of moulers, but only one Ramuthra. But at least this gives a lower bound on the number of actual spirits.